# How to create a secure tunnel to expose my node,js app without using ngrok

Tags: botframework, ngrok

```
Ubuntu 20.04
Apache2
```

I have been developing a Microsoft Teams Tab and I am running it on my own cloud-based server. I have tested using `ngrok` and it is working great. Now I need to move away from using `ngrok` and tunnel my node.js myself **without** using `ngrok`

Problem is that I am new to node.js and so some of this I am just learning. From my understanding, I need to use `gulp`/`browsersync` but I am not sure if I am heading in the right direction. I have tried many different configs in my `gulpfile.js` file but nothing seems to work.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: 'teams.example.com',
        open: false
    });
});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how I can create a secure tunnel?

Comment: Could you please try this [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel).

Comment: Did documentation shared by Jagadeesh helped?